# Dynamically composed icons representing state of content

Tags: website-design, icon

I am considering a web UI imrpovement. Each icon (large, 128x128px) in flow layout represents a configuration of a certain process, and, to the user, there are a bunch of "important" settings for this process and dozens of less important ones. I would like to incorporate 3-5 most important paradigms into a single icon (say, long or short process, repeating or one-time, secure to use anywhere or for private network only...). Obviously, elements should rime and co-ordinate, but I believe it is possible to make every combination visually appealing and compositionally correct. I would then use stacked PNGs with alpha transparency.

I am a bit concerned that it is a dead end that has been tried before. Why is this approach not widedely used? Do you see any theorertical/conceptual blockers?

*Update*

Here is an illustration, without styling or giving it too much thought, but the idea should be clear:

[image]

First is a large secure scheduled task, second is distributed duplication process. Wouldn't a user, on average, identify the necessary item faster than if every item was a card with text? Obviously, the same glyphs (shown in blue) will be used in the editor itself to create a mental connection.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resource gathering which is not within the defined scope of this site.

Comment: I will re-phrase.

Comment: Your asking the icons do to a whole lot of work.

Comment: I added an illustration. I kind of see your point. It is a whole lot of thinking for designer to come up with rules too.

Comment: Could perhaps be faster for you generate dynamically the icons from the rules using SVG and Javascript?

Comment: I think it is a good idea. It is also easier to handle if icon size needs to change or adapt for a device (even though there are no foreseeable plans).

Comment: @AlexPakka See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034712/creating-svg-graphics-using-javascript. On the net there are interesting tutorials: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/scripting.html, http://raphaeljs.com, http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics, http://www.svgjs.com, ...

Comment: Perhaps [this site](http://fig.decodingweb.com/) may be helpful in some way